# Qual a nossa responsabilidade ao linkar manuais de bibliotecas em inglês?

Tags: debate, idioma, documentação

Com frequência as soluções para as perguntas neste site são exemplos de utilização de uma biblioteca, onde, se a pessoa que perguntou já conhecesse tal biblioteca, nem precisaria fazer a pergunta. Alguém que conhece, vai lá, mostra como resolver o problema utilizando um `import libIradaQueVcNaoConhecia`, e demonstrando o funcionamento básico, ainda coloca o link pro manual da biblioteca, para o usuário pesquisar todas as utilidades da ferramenta.

Quando foi a última vez que você viu um manual de software em português? Não é um trabalho muito raso termos o SOpt para mandar o pessoal aprender a ler manual em inglês?

Eu estou exagerando. É claro que o SOpt está servindo para aumentar o alcance da troca de informação do SO, mesmo que a barreira da língua ainda esteja erguida mais para frente, mas até onde temos que ir no esforço de trazer este conteúdo para o português?

Comment: Excelente pergunta. Não entendi os negativos, visto que levanta uma questão pertinente.

Comment: Como curiosidade, até existia uma [área do site p/ documentação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/documentation), mas [foi desativada](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354217). Enfim, se não existe material em português (ou existe, mas a tradução é ruim), ainda sim eu prefiro colocar o link em inglês, pois é melhor do que não ter nenhum. Acho que o trabalho só é raso qdo a resposta possui **apenas** o link (ou uma explicação incompleta/errada deste). Se tiver uma explicação boa sobre como usar para resolver aquele problema específico (tanto o código qto os conceitos, etc), é perfeitamente válido

Comment: @hkotsubo Era exatamente algo como esta área de documentação que eu esperava que saísse dessa pergunta, mas em português. Que pena que já foi feito a falhou. Dificilmente verá a luz do dia novamente.

Answer (score 13):

> até onde temos que ir no esforço de trazer este conteúdo para o português

Os conteúdos **canônicos** de documentação estão em inglês na esmagadora maioria dos casos. Já é um bônus existir algo em português, que dirá algo de qualidade. E dá trabalho encontrar isso. Então, "até onde temos que ir"? Até onde for a disposição de cada um para localizar e avaliar esse conteúdo antes de linkar.

> Não é um trabalho muito raso termos o SOpt para mandar o pessoal aprender a ler manual em inglês?

Não. Nunca é errado linkar para conteúdos canônicos. O SOpt existe sim para ajudar a superar a barreira da língua, mas não tem como dar conta de tudo. Qualquer pessoa que queira programar precisa ter um mínimo de compreensão de leitura técnica em inglês. Por esse ponto de vista, passar um link em inglês pode até ser visto como incentivo.

Answer (score 4):

Sim, tem muitos usuários que fazem essas *"quick-answers"*, as vezes nem tem como evitar, mas alguns bons usuários procuram complementar mais, muitas documentações nem sempre trazem uma boa experiencia de compreensão, mas são bons gatilhos para saber o uso "correto" de uma tecnologia especifica.

Eu pessoalmente concordo com a necessidade da sua pergunta, para fazer algo que fazia a algum tempo e recentemente tenho evitado, criticar certos tipos respostas, não como critica negativo, falo isso no ÓTIMO SENTIDO, falo de abordar mais se possivel, aqui no site eu posso citar ótimos exemplos de usuários que quando respondem geralmente junto passam suas experiencias e conhecimento técnico sobre o assunto e abordando até situações aonde aquela função/tecnologia implicaria em "um possível problema" ou "mal uso".

Infelizmente esses usuários costumam ser criticados por outros usuários que não entendem a real necessidade de passar mais do que uma resposta-rapida qualquer, isso acaba por tirar a motivação destes valorosos colaboradores, alguns que infelizmente notei diminuírem suas respostas/contribuições no site devido a uma batalha quase perdida contra respostas de usuários que "adoram chutar" respostas e cometer uma série de gafes, certa vez notei um usuário, que tenho certeza que aprendeu expressão regular com as minhas respostas, chutar uma resposta e ainda argumentar como se dominasse bem o assunto, mas a expressão regular tinha uma gafe, algo que era para ser como isto:

```
^[abc123]+$
```

Foi respondido como isto

```
^[a|b|c|1|2|3]+$
```

O usuário claramente se baseou em um raso conhecimento sobre o assunto misturando com uma provável leitura dinâmica em outras respostas e acabou por pensar que em `[...]` (colchetes ou parênteses retos) usava-se o `|` (*barra vertical* ou *pipe*) como se fosse `OR`, para quem conhece regex sabe que o pipe ali não faz sentido.

Ok, a primeira vista que você ler isto vai parecer que estou exagerando, mas imagine uma série de gafes assim, ainda com upvotes de pessoas inocentes que acreditam realmente que aquilo parece estar correto e volta e meia uma resposta do tipo ainda ser marcada como correta, isso com o tempo vira uma bola de neve de gafes e o nosso querido site, que era visto como um bom lugar para se obter ajuda se torna até possivelmente um alvo de piadas.

Para alguns isto pode não ser um problema, mas para aqueles que se esforçam em trazer seus bons conhecimentos técnicos, isso é muito triste sim. Por isto mais que citar fontes de links deve(ria) ser uma "obrigação" olharmos com mais calma respostas boas, dos quais vão além de um "faça assim ... conforme documentação [link]" e apoiarmos este conteudo com experiencias técnicas e de usuários que já demonstraram ter o conhecimento real e não em respostas só baseadas em algum tipo de "leitura dinamica" para ganhar "score".

Espero não ter fugido do assunto.

Comment: Acho que da forma que eu exemplifiquei você ficou com uma impressão diferente. Eu quis exemplificar o que eu mesmo faço. Eu aponto uma biblioteca que servirá para ajudar, e mostro o código necessário para solucionar a questão. Só que, a partir do momento que quem perguntou usar o código que eu coloquei, essa pessoa está "refém" do funcionamento específico daquela biblioteca, dos métodos e objetos inclusos. E **vai precisar** ler adiante no manual para continuar o desenvolvimento do código. Vai além do problema que gerou a pergunta.

Comment: @Rocchi como disse, acho sua pergunta aqui no meta totalmente necessária/util, a ideia que dei de exemplo é fornecer/oferecer sua experiencia real com a tal tecnologia, muito além de citar links, agregar, mas procurando sempre fazer um bom apontamento "técnico".

Comment: @Rocchi Se vc explicou como usar a lib p/ resolver aquele problema específico e colocou um link em inglês p/ o qual não há tradução em português, não há muito mais o que fazer. Se a pessoa tem outro problema diferente que envolve a mesma lib, ou ela cria outra pergunta, ou procura material em português, ou aprende inglês - p/ alguns parece "elitista" e "cruel" dizer que "inglês é obrigatório" (nem todos têm condições de aprender), mas é fato que a maioria do material de TI está em inglês e não é traduzida (e quando é, nem sempre a tradução é boa), então não tem muito o que fazer...

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Certo. Eu posso fazer um esforço maior para ir além da pergunta, mas ao mesmo tempo isso cria um diferencial em relação ao SOen, onde uma _quick-answer_ pode ser inteiramente útil, não necessitando de nada mais, enquanto que aqui temos que nos aproximar mais do formato que o stack exchange foi criado pra substituir, onde apenas os experts respondiam perguntas. Pode parecer bom a princípio, mas eram comunidades pagas, e caras.  De toda forma, levei a sério o que você disse. Dá, sim, pra ir mais longe.

Comment: @hkotsubo Não me parece elitista, não. Apenas um pouco triste. Pior ainda é ficar encarregado de estabelecer o limite do conhecimento trazido ao considerar quem não vai conseguir a documentação citada, mas é verdade o que você disse, se o usuário tiver uma nova pergunta sobre o material depois que a primeira pergunta foi solucionada, basta abrir uma pergunta nova. Desde que fique bem explicado, é quase como ter uma tradução do manual.